# Driving distance between two places - android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have two latitude-longitude pairs and I want to calculate the driving distance between them.
I used the Location.distanceBetween() method for this. But what this returns is not the driving distance. It is a smaller value than the driving distance. Can someone say what distance it returns?

Can I find the actual driving distance using the Google Maps android API v2? How?

Comment: It returns the straight-line distance -- as the crow flies.

Comment: @antlersoft How to find the driving distance then?

Comment: You have to get driving directions to find driving distance

Comment: Can I do this using google maps android api? can u provide links to some useful tutorials for this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/